# Using HAProxy To Redirect to IP

Tags: haproxy

We have a situation where we need to redirect traffic to a server with a particular IP based on the subdomain of the request.

For example:

- if the request is https://subdomain01.abc.com send the request to server with ip 1.2.3.4
- if the request is https://subdomain02.abc.com send the request to server with ip 1.2.3.10
- if the request is https://subdomain03.abc.com send the request to server with ip 1.2.25.25

Is this possible with haProxy?  I'm thinking that this is possible but I can't find any good examples that simulate this.

If this is possible, are there any limits to the number of rules we can use?

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction (or for letting me know that this is not a good use-case for haproxy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Can it be achieved with HA-Proxy? Yes.
- Are there any limits on the rules? No.
- Should you implement this use case with HA-Proxy? I don't think so. A simpler proxy would do the job, since you're not loadbalancing.

This is what you want to include on the `haproxy.cfg` file if you want to test:

```
global
    ...

defaults
    ...

frontend https_frontend
    bind *:443
    mode http

    acl subdomain01_acl hdr(host) -i subdomain01.abc.com
    acl subdomain02_acl hdr(host) -i subdomain02.abc.com
    acl subdomain03_acl hdr(host) -i subdomain03.abc.com

    use_backend server1_backend if subdomain01_acl
    use_backend server2_backend if subdomain02_acl
    use_backend server3_backend if subdomain03_acl

backend server1_backend
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server server1 1.2.3.4:80

backend server2_backend
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server server2 1.2.3.10:80

backend server3_backend
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    server server3 1.2.25.25:80
```

Comment: thanks.  You're correct, there's no load balancing required for this particular project.  Do you have a recommendation for a simpler proxy tool?

Comment: Nothing special. Whatever you feel comfortable with. My choice would be probably nginx, but as I said, any proxy would fit this use case.